# How can I iteratively transpose vertical lists to horizontal entries?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of about 400 companies, including their addresses, phone numbers and industry categories in the following format.

```
Column A

Prestige Automotive
1234 Jefferson Drive
Anywhere, TX 54321 
Phone: 000-000-0000
Primary Category: Manufacturing 
Jefferson Grocery 
4321 Washington Drive 
Anywhere, TX 54321 
Phone: 111-111-1111
Primary Category: Grocers
...
```

I need to reformat the data so that it is listed horizontally, in the following format

```
Prestige Automotive|1234 Jefferson Drive|Anywhere, TX 54321|000-000-0000|Manufacturing

Jefferson Grocery|4321 Washington Drive|Anywhere, TX 54321|111-111-1111
```

What would be the fastest way to do this in excel without having to manually transpose each company block? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing this, one way is to iterate over the data and concatenate it. Below is code that will work if your data is consistent.

```
Sub Concat()

Dim startRow As Integer             'the row to start in the spreadsheet
Dim rowsToProcess As Integer        'total number of records to process
Dim itemsPerAddress As Integer      'the items per record
Dim horizontalRow As String         'hold the concatenated data
Dim currentRow As Integer           'the row to start at for the current iteration

startRow = 1
rowsToProcess = 2
itemsPerAddress = 5

'set the active sheet to start, this could be set to any sheet
Set sh = ActiveSheet

'start the process of looping each record
For x = startRow To rowsToProcess

    horizontalRow = ""
    currentRow = (x - 1) * itemsPerAddress + 1

    'loop over the fields for the current record
    For y = 1 To itemsPerAddress
        If (y <= 3) Then
            horizontalRow = horizontalRow & sh.Cells(currentRow, 1).Value & "|"
        Else
            If (y = 4) Then
                horizontalRow = horizontalRow & Mid(sh.Cells(currentRow, 1).Value, 8) & "|"
            Else
                horizontalRow = horizontalRow & Mid(sh.Cells(currentRow, 1).Value, 18)
            End If
        End If
        currentRow = currentRow + 1
        'here you could do something with the horizontal row, paste it in another sheet or save to file
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: It might be "neater"(?) if the outer loop was `For x = startRow to lastRow Step itemsPerAddress` (where lastRow was set using one of the normal methods) and, within the inner loop, you could then just use `x - 1 + y` instead of `currentRow`.

Comment: You are of course right @YowE3K, you could also replace the inner loop and access via array - as always there are many solutions to the problem.